# Как вывести что - то после основного контента WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, hook

На WooComerce делал хуком к такой функции:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content','add_desc_on_page' );
```

А без WooComerce как вывести до или после в не зависимости от того какая страница, одиночный пост или архивы, или категории и т.д.?

Answer (score 1):

В Woocommerce хук вызывается, например, в шаблоне `single-product.php` следующим образом:

```
  <?php 
      /** 
       * woocommerce_before_main_content hook 
       * 
       * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper - 10 (outputs opening divs for the content) 
       * @hooked woocommerce_breadcrumb - 20 
       */ 
      do_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content' ); 
  ?> 

      <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?> 

          <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' ); ?> 

      <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?> 

  <?php 
      /** 
       * woocommerce_after_main_content hook 
       * 
       * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end - 10 (outputs closing divs for the content) 
       */ 
      do_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content' ); 
  ?>
```

В стандартном (или любом другом используемом Вами) шаблоне нужно поступать точно так же. Находите, где в шаблоне выводится контент (с помощью функции `the_content()` или `get_template_part('content')`), и вызываете нужную функцию. Для создания собственного хука используйте функцию `add_action()`.

Comment: А что если сайт сделан так, что нет функции, и вывод контента идет через самый обычный цикл? Как тогда поступать?

Comment: Не очень поняла, чего нет. Если сайт сделан на `Wordpress`, то функции `the_content()` и `get_template_part` доступны для использования. `add_action` тоже. Внутри цикла используйте нужный вам код.